# Laravel 5.4 Tymon JWT Auth Guard Driver Not Defined

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I've implemented Tymon JWT for Laravel 5.4 & its working fine with users (default) model.

However, I want it to work for api guard not default web.

If I set default guard to api & set api driver to token as:

```
'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'app_users',
    ],
```

I get following error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::attempt()
```

If I set api driver to jwt-auth, I get follwing error

```
Auth guard driver [api] is not defined.
```

Interestingly it works fine If I change driver to session.

```
'api' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'api_users',
    ],
```

Just wanted to know what driver should I set for JWT api tokens, as session driver is for web only?

Answer (score 5):

Posting answer to my question:

There is no guard support for **JWT 0.5.** You will need to use one of the latest **1.0.0-** versions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Tymon JWT package, 1.0 beta version, you can implement jwt guard very easily.

Documentation for that feature is not ready yet, but you can follow this mini-tutorial https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/860